ROS2 Humble - FastRTPS - Bad performance on wireless network with multiple robots
I have multiple robots, that I want to run on a wireless network, and control them from the base station. The robots must work even if the network connection is bad/there isn't one.
The robots have an Nvidia Jetson, that is connected to a wlan network, on which the control PC is. The Jetson is connected with Ethernet cable to Raspberry Pi, that handles robot controls, reads firmware,...
If I connect one robot, it works well, however, connecting one more, the whole network crashes, ros2 messages are received by PC 10, 15s later than needed, and most are dropped. I recorded the start of 2 robots in Wireshark. There seems to be a big UDP packet burst on every robot's start, however the packet speed never fully slows down. As seen in the graph:
My Fast DDS config file is as follows:
<transport_descriptors>
    <transport_descriptor>
        <transport_id>user_transport</transport_id>
        <type>UDPv4</type>
    </transport_descriptor>
</transport_descriptors>

<participant profile_name="participant profile" is_default_profile="true">
    <rtps>
        <userTransports>
            <transport_id>user_transport</transport_id>
        </userTransports>
        <useBuiltinTransports>false</useBuiltinTransports>
    </rtps>
</participant>

<!-- default publisher profile -->
<publisher profile_name="default_publisher" is_default_profile="true">
    <historyMemoryPolicy>DYNAMIC</historyMemoryPolicy>
    <qos>
        <publishMode>
            <kind>ASYNCHRONOUS</kind>
        </publishMode>
    </qos>
</publisher>

<!-- default subscriber profile -->
<subscriber profile_name="default_subscriber" is_default_profile="true">
    <historyMemoryPolicy>DYNAMIC</historyMemoryPolicy>
</subscriber>

I feel like the problem is the UDP bursts. Network router sometimes also crashes (Couriously, only the 5Ghz connection, 2.4Ghz keeps being on).
I'm also attaching the Wireshark file, if anybody could help me out.
Thank you so much!!
